# (Exports) How to access an app object inside of controllers in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, next.js

Im trying to figure out how to access an app object from route controllers. In my routes file i have

```
const apiController = require('../controllers/mainController')
module.exports = (app) => {


    app.post("/stop",
        apiController.stopFlow
    );

    app.post("/specificSearch",
        apiController.initiateSearch);
}
```

By some reason, I cannot access `(app)` object inside of these controllers, however, if I do something like

```
module.exports = (app) =>{

    app.post('/stop', (req,res)=>{
        console.log(app)
    })

}
```

Then everything works fine, so I was curious is there a way to pass it to my `apiController`? My `apiController` looks like this

```
module.exports = {

    async stopFlow(req, res) {
        console.log("Stop");

        console.log(app)

    },
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Why do you want to access `app`, I can't imagine any reason why accessing `app` itself will be necessary or usefull in any way while a request takes place. It seems that you trie to solve a problem in a wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Express, you can use `req.app` from inside of any request handler to get access to the `app` object.  It's explained right [here in the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app).

Comment: That is indeed what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The request object has an [app](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.app) proeprty:

> This property holds a reference to the instance of the Express application that is using the middleware.

Beside that can always pass objects around using a the request obejct and a middleware that you register before the other middlewars that should have access to that object.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   req.theApp = app
   req.someDbConnection = dbConnection
})
```

And then in the other middleware/route:

```
app.post('/stop', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.theApp)
    console.log(req.someDbConnection)
})
```

You might want to use a namespace that is unique to your project to pass those object:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   req.Stas = req.Stas || {}
   req.Stas.theApp = app
   req.Stas.someDbConnection = dbConnection
})
```